# Mongoose: callback of findOne doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I made a callback function called sendShortUrl and I tested to print something in the function but It didn't print anything. can you guys help me?

```
app.post('/api/compress', (req, res) => {
  let longUrl = checkURL(req.body.url);
  Url.findOne({long_url: longUrl}, sendShortUrl(err, doc, longUrl));
});


function sendShortUrl(err, doc, longUrl) {
  if(err) console.error(err);
  console.log("success");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is this:

```
app.post('/api/compress', (req, res) => {
  let longUrl = checkURL(req.body.url);

  function sendShortUrl(err, doc) {
    if(err) console.error(err);
    console.log("success");
  }

  Url.findOne({long_url: longUrl}, sendShortUrl);
});
```

Then `sendShortUrl` will have access to `longUrl`, without passing it as a parameter.

**Explanation:**

Lets say you have a function, and inside it another function:

```
function a(param1, param2) {

   var param3 = 12;

   // in this scope, you have access to param1, param2, param3

   function b(param4) {
       // in this scope, you have access to param1, param2, param3, param4
   } 

   funcWithCallback(something, b); // calling funcWithCallback with some parameter and my b function

}
```

When `funcWithCallback` executes the function `b` that I've passed as reference (same thing that does mongoose with your callback), `b` will have access to `param1, param2, param3, param4`. 
That is called **lexical scoping**, and it's the way that javascript behaves.

Brief definition:

> Lexical Scoping defines how variable names are resolved in nested
>   functions: inner functions contain the scope of parent functions even
>   if the parent function has returned.

In your case, when you pass your function reference to `findOne`, your function has access to the variables defined inside it, the parameters passed to it, and the scope of the direct parent function (the controller).

Comment: then how can I pass longUrl variable?

Comment: Was that there before? In your example you dont need it. Anyway, Mongoose will call the function you pass with the posible errors and the doc found. If you need any variable from the outer scope, you can use them inside the callback function.

Comment: I got an error when I try to access longUrl variable in callback function. It says longUrl variable. basically there's a scope problem and outer scope doesn't pass variable to callback function.

Comment: You need to define your callback function inside of the controller function (or where you have defined the variable that you want to use inside). I'm not close to a computer but  in a few hours i could give you a more descriptive answer.

Comment: Function passed as reference brings with them the scope in where they are defined.

Comment: So you mean that I can't define any functions out of the controller function?

Comment: No, that's not the case. You can't define any functions that need a variable that is not defined inside, outside of the scope that that variable is defined.  I'll try to edit my answer.

Comment: @PhillipYS Just edited the answer, take a look and please comment again if something is still not clear!

Answer (score 0):

In that code you are executing a function, in order for the callback ro work, you need to pass the function intended to be the callback to `url.findOne()`.

```
app.post('/api/compress', (req, res) => 
{   
    let longUrl = checkURL(req.body.url);   
    Url.findOne({long_url: longUrl}, sendShortUrl())); 
});


function sendShortUrl()
{
   return function(err, doc) 
    {
         if(err) console.error(err);   
         console.log(doc); 
         console.log(longUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got an error when I try to access longUrl variable in callback function. It says longUrl variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can Simply tap into doc to check if you found the document or not.

```
if(!doc){
    console.log("custom error statement");
}
```